# pg_largeobject access on heroku

Tags: database, postgresql, heroku

I'm trying to clean up my postgres database on heroku where some large objects have gotten out of control and I want to remove large objects which aren't used anymore.

On my dev machine, I can do:

```
select distinct loid from pg_largeobject 
Where loid Not In (select id from table )
```

then i run:

```
SELECT lo_unlink(loid)
```

on each of those IDs.

But on heroku, i can't run any selects on `pg_largeobject`, as even

```
select * from pg_largeobject limit 1;
```

gives me an error:

```
ERROR:  permission denied for relation pg_largeobject
```

Any suggestions how to work around this, or actually even why we don't have read access on `pg_largeobject` in heroku?

Comment: What does `\dp+ pg_catalog.pg_largeobject` show?

Comment: Schema   |      Name      | Type  | Access privileges | Column access privileges 
 ------------+----------------+-------+-------------------+--------------------------
  pg_catalog | pg_largeobject | table |                   |

Comment: sorry not very visible, but no access privs

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since PostgreSQL 9.0, a non-superuser can't access `pg_largeobject`. This is documented in the release notes:

> Add the ability to control large object (BLOB) permissions with
>   GRANT/REVOKE (KaiGai Kohei)
>
> Formerly, any database user could read or modify any large object.
>   Read and write permissions can now be granted and revoked per large
>   object, and the ownership of large objects is tracked.

If it works on your development instance, it's either because it's version `8.4` or lower, or because you're logged in as a superuser.

If you can't log in as a superuser on heroku, I guess you could dump the remote database with `pg_dump`, then reload it locally, identify the leaked OIDs as a local superuser, put them in a script with the `lo_unlink` commands, and finally play this script against the heroku instance.

**Update:**

Based on how the psql `\dl` command queries the database, it appears that `pg_catalog.pg_largeobject_metadata` can be used to retrieve the OIDs and ownership of all large objects, through this query:

```
SELECT oid as "ID",
  pg_catalog.pg_get_userbyid(lomowner) as "Owner",
  pg_catalog.obj_description(oid, 'pg_largeobject') as "Description"
  FROM pg_catalog.pg_largeobject_metadata   ORDER BY oid
```

So your initial query finding the leaked large objects could be changed for non-superusers with 9.0+ into:

```
select oid from pg_largeobject_metadata
 Where oid Not In (select id from table )
```

and if necessary, a condition on `lomowner` could be added to filter on the large objects owned by a specific user.

Comment: ok, i'm su in dev. is there no way of listing the available large object IDs which the current user has access to?

Comment: ah thanks. I actually had looked at the metadata table. but the documentation (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/catalog-pg-largeobject-metadata.html) and the query select * from pg_largeobject_metadata does not suggest anything about an oid field - so i completely missed that.

Comment: i also discovered that you can run `vacuumlo` on heroku postgres. this cleanups up the data as well and is a bit more clever, since it seems to have a different way of detecting used large objects - you don't need to specify the table which contains the large objects.

Comment: Yes, `vacuumlo` considers any column of type `oid` in non-system tables. Also it gets the existing large objects from `pg_largeobject_metadata` in 9.0+ (`pg_largeobject` for older versions)