# Postgres 9.3 Backup and Restore Error

Tags: postgresql

Fine i have taken backup of my database using "pg_dump" utility(dump file
name is "testbackup.sql").Before restoring it back,i dropped all
tables,view,sequences,functions which i have created. After that using
"psql" command try to restore the dump back.But it shows the duplicate-key
violation error.
**

> Error : psql.bin:testbackup.sql:17884: ERROR:  duplicate key value
>   violates unique constraint "pg_largeobject_metadata_oid_index".

**I googled in internet
but i cant come to a correct solution.so Kindly provide us theproper
solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you forgot to drop all large objects. List their IDs by checking in [`pg_largeobject`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-largeobject.html) and delete them using [`lo_unlink`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/lo-interfaces.html#LO-UNLINK).

Answer (score 1):

To answer this a bit more explicitly - execute the following query to clear large objects (LOs):

```
SELECT lo_unlink(loid) FROM pg_largeobject;
```

In certain environments [you might not be able to do this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15014692/pg-largeobject-access-on-heroku) and get the following:

> ERROR:  permission denied for table pg_largeobject
>
> CONTEXT:  SQL statement "SELECT lo_unlink(loid) FROM pg_largeobject"

Then a workaround is to do this instead:

```
SELECT lo_unlink(oid) FROM pg_largeobject_metadata;
```

You might still encounter errors of this form...

> ERROR: large object 123456789 does not exist

...which means that your database contains unreferenced large objects.

These can be cleared with PostgreSQL's `vacuumlo` utility (not an SQL query):

```
vacuumlo [DATABASE]
```